# How to reduce this multiple and- and or- conditions in sql-statement?

Tags: database, sql-optimization, database-optimization

I´ve got an optimizing question about SQL.

Is there a way to reduce this sql syntax:

```
Select * from TABLE 
where 
COLUMN != 'abc' and 
COLUMN != 'def' and 
COLUMN != 'xau' and 
COLUMN != 'def' and 
COLUMN != 'eag' and 
COLUMN != 'dff' and 
COLUMN != 'www'
```

and second sql syntax

```
Select * from TABLE 
where 
COLUMN = 'abc' or 
COLUMN = 'def' or 
COLUMN = 'xau' or 
COLUMN = 'def' or 
COLUMN = 'eag' or 
COLUMN = 'dff' or 
COLUMN = 'www'
```

Comment: The second one is true for any value.

Comment: sorry I changed != to =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Multiple OR condition can be re-written using:

```
Select * from TABLE 
where 
COLUMN not in('abc','def','xau','def','eag','dff','www')
```

Multiple AND condition, can you enlighten me when its possible that same column have more than 1 value?

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe you can solve the second sql-statement too.

Comment: Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

USING Boolean ALGEBRA:

1st:  `(!x)AND(!y)..AND(!z) == !(x or y...or z)`

Meaning:

```
 Select * from TABLE WHERE COLUMN NOT IN ('abc','def',...)





    2nd:  (!x)or(!y)..or(!z)==!(x AND Y AND ..Z) 
 however  the intersection of  x AND Y ... AND Z  is the empty set.
So  (!x)or(!y)..or(!z)==!(x AND Y AND ..Z)  = !(False) = True.

Meaning:

    Select * from TABLE  //no WHERE CLAUSE NEEDED
```